# Endless Redirects Suddenly Disable Site

Tags: redirect

Quite suddenly our company site began throwing a 301 redirect error. I've disabled our most recent plugin additions (old additions) and have looked for any kind of recent code adjustments in the theme that might have contributed to the problem. Nothing obvious.

As a quick fix, I installed Mark Jaquith's Permalink Fix & Disable Canonical Redirects Pack. This has fixed the redirect problem but, whether because of or independent of the plugin, now all internal links fail.

I've checked the root  level .htaccess file to see if any changes have been made. It's just your standard rewrite rule set for a subfolder installation.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /new/index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Is there any other place I ought to be looking for smoking guns? Anyway to scan files for redirect problems?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just tried to switch out themes to Woothemes' Placeholder and noticed that ajax form featured in the admin are also not working. It seems that this is a server issue rather than something resident in my files or settings. Could that be true?

Comment: Have you enabled anything on your server, made any changes to the server that might have affected it?

Comment: It's very possible. The problem is that our site is on an hosted account managed by the gentleman who constructed our old site. So I'm afraid if the troubleshooting is server side, it may take a while to figure out what the issue is. It may be time to make a break and get our own space.

Comment: Do you know who the site is hosted with?

Comment: It's with Dreamhost.

Comment: Ahh okay i wonder if they've enable the new 'CloudFlare' service, that caused a number of redirect problems for me. Find out if they have and i know the solution if they have.

Comment: Aha. That's a good lead Alex. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like CloudFlare just went live. Any idea what the cause of the troubles is. It would sure be nice to have some kind of inocculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looks like CloudFlare just went live. Any idea what the cause of the
>   troubles is. It would sure be nice to have some kind of inocculation.

Okay in that case, CloudFlare requires that you use the "Add WWW" option here. However, if your WordPress install isn't told to do the same, they conflict and result in the infinite redirect loop. So, in your WordPress dashboard, go to Settings > General:

Both "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" on that page should both have the 'www' manually added there so that it will cooperate when dreamhost forces the same.

Try that

Comment: This solved it for me! Thanks a million Alex. Is there anything I can do to increase your creds here?

Comment: Fantastic, happy to help! Not much you can do on here. Maybe a mention on twitter would help though :).

Comment: Oh and i might suggest you have a quiet word in "the gentleman who constructed" your old site and ask him not to make server changes without consulting you first!